# Typescript ts-nocheck seems to be ignored

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I set `// @ts-nocheck` But I still get the typescript errors

[image]

```
OS: Catalina
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. It's hard to read, links can break, and people cannot just copy & paste it to try it. See [ask].

Comment: rephrased the title and body, to get straight to the point

Answer (score 8):

`ts-nocheck` [to only have meaning in JS files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26887)

This is implemented in TypeScript 3.7 beta: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/